# Looping over Outlook mail items in "Sent Items" folder

Tags: vb.net, interop, outlook

We're trying to access the **Sent Items** folder in **Outlook 2007 (using Exchange)** but the test for `TypeOf(i) Is Outlook.MailItem` in the below code snippet always returns False.

We know we have the right folder because a test for `items.Count` returns the correct number of mail items.

Inbox messages are fine. If we change the folder from `olFolderSentMail` to `olFolderInbox` the test for `TypeOf(i) Is Outlook.MailItem` passes and it's quite happy to show us the Subject.

```
Dim app As Outlook.Application = Nothing
Dim ns As Outlook.NameSpace = Nothing
Dim siFolder As Outlook.Folder = Nothing
Dim items As Outlook.Items = Nothing

app = New Outlook.Application()
ns = app.Session


siFolder = CType(ns.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail), Outlook.Folder)

items = siFolder.Items

MsgBox(items.Count)

For Each i In items

    If TypeOf (i) Is Outlook.MailItem Then
        Dim mailitem As Outlook.MailItem
        mailitem = CType(i, Outlook.MailItem)
        MsgBox(mailitem.Subject)
    Else
        MsgBox("not a mailitem")
    End If
Next
```

### Update

@Rob's answer below, yes, definitely has helped. But I'm still puzzled. The crucial thing @Rob's code is doing is testing for `.MessageClass = "IPM.Note"`. If I include that then the later test for `TypeOf x Is MailItem` succeeds. If I replace @Rob's test for `.MessageClass = "IPM.Note"` with `If True Then` then the same code still executes but the later test for Is MailItem fails. It's as if just testing for the `.MessageClass` automagically resolves the object into a MailItem.

Furthermore the Sent Items don't contain any meeting requests so the test would seem to be unnecessary anyway.

Answer (score 2):

This should get you going ...

....

```
Dim oSent As Outlook.MAPIFolder = oNS.GetFolderFromID(gSentEntryID, gSentStoreID)


 Dim oItems As Outlook.Items = oSent.Items

 For i as Integer = 1 To oItems.Count
   'Test to make sure item is a mail item and not a meeting request.
    If oItems.Item(i).MessageClass = "IPM.Note" Then

        If TypeOf oItems.Item(i) Is Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem Then

             .....
```

Comment: Rob, yes this definitely got me going but I'm still puzzled. see my edits.