# Iterating through Inbox Items in Outlook 2010 with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, outlook, add-in

I am trying to write an add-in to Outlook 2010 that will iterate through all items in a specific mail folder and auto-populate an Excel spreadsheet from there. At the moment, I am having difficulty getting access to even the default Inbox. I am writing the add-in from Visual Studio 2010 Pro, and utilizing the auto-complete options as necessary. My problem is that whenever I run my code, even just to set basic variables, it will give me an "Object not found" error and throw an exception. I have no idea what is wrong, and I would immensely appreciate any assistance.

```vb
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop

Public Class ThisAddIn

    Private Sub ThisAddIn_Startup() Handles Me.Startup
        Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
        Dim olNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
        Dim olFolders As Object
        Dim olReadFolder As Outlook.Folder
        Dim readCollection As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Items
        Dim currentMessage As Outlook.MailItem
        Dim exWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet

        olApp = New Outlook.Application
        olNamespace = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
        'olFolders = olNamespace.Folders
        olReadFolder = olNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox)     '<-- Add-in fails here


    End Sub

    Private Sub ThisAddIn_Shutdown() Handles Me.Shutdown

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, this isn't VBA and since you mentioned VS 2010 in the question, I changed the tags and title to reflect.

Comment: Check Looping over Outlook mail items in “Sent Items” folder[1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5044906/looping-over-outlook-mail-items-in-sent-items-folder

Comment: Ah, sorry, didn't mean to put this in the wrong spot. I suppose this is Visual Basic, isn't it? Still a little new to .NET :)

Comment: No worries, you are in the right place. I don't use VS, but wouldn't that line require a `Set` statement since `GetDefaultFolder` returns an object?

Comment: I had thought so, but VS2010 flags it as incorrect syntax. I honestly thought the Set statement was required as well, I am still learning what VS wants from me.